# How to remove sound comming from servo motor?

Tags: arduino, servomotor

When ever i move the servo motors from the arduino, it produces sound. I don't want the servos to make this sound. How can i remove this sound. As i think this sound must be coming from the gears used inside the servo motor, but how can i silent those sound?

Comment: There is no "turn noise off"-trick. You could try to put something around the motors to dampen the noise.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the skill, it may help to open the servo and apply some vaseline to the gear, while not messing with the electronic. If you are not totally sure you have the required skill, you probably have not and will just destroy the servo.

So you have just the normal way to suppress sound:

- put it inside box
- use foam around the box
- attach the servo well, so it would not vibrate
- suppress those vibration too (usually put some rubber between servo and the base and/or between the base and rest of your device)

Keep in mind, that the servo is manipulating something, so there must be free way for it and that the servo generate a lot of heat, when it moves or protects from move, so it may need also cooling